# How can set idle time in android apps

Tags: android

if the user not interact to the any screen in the some time in android apps then automatic to the redirect login page 
please help me 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

get user last interation time as below:

override in your activity

```
@Override
    public void onUserInteraction() {
        super.onUserInteraction();
        mUserLastInteraction = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
```

then onResume of activity do this:

```
 mLogoutTaskTimer = new Timer(true); 
            // TODO: (AS) APPARENT BUG IN AUTO LOGOUT ON INACTIVITY
            long currentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            long timeSlice = PSCONST.LOGOUT_TIME_IN_MIN * 60 * 1000;

            if (currentTime - mUserLastInteraction >= timeSlice) 
            {
                 mUtils.signout();
                 finish();
            }
```